# What does SWIG do by default with a double* argument that is an output?

Tags: swig

This is my first encounter with SWIG, and I'm not finding anything useful by searching, which probably means I'm not even looking in the right direction. If someone could get me vectored, that would be great.

I have a C function that takes a double* as an argument and uses it as an output:

```
int myFunc(double* p, int len){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    p[i] = (double)i;
  }
return 0;
}
```

To wrap it, I didn't do anything tricky or custom, I just let SWIG do whatever it does by default:

```
%module MyModule
 %{
 /* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
 #include "MyModule.h"
 %}

 /* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
 %include "MyModule.h"
```

This all worked in that it compiled and built a module I can load. However, one might reasonably expect to be able to call this from Python like this, and I can't:

```
numbers = [0.0]*5
myFunc(numbers, 5)
```

SWIG complains that the first argument is the wrong type. I've been reading about a thing called typemaps.i that lets you specify type conversions manually. Is this necessary for something as standard as this example? I'd be grateful if someone could tell me what I should read or Google for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using builtin types as input parameters with SWIG is handled automatically, but SWIG needs some help with output parameters.  Below is a simple way to do it.

Note that `%inline` is a way to add a function and a SWIG wrapper for it in a `.i` file instead of making a header file and using `#include` and `%include`.  It's good for small examples.

Reference: [carrays.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_carrays)

```
%module x

%include <carrays.i>
%array_functions(double,doubles)

%inline %{
int myFunc(double* p, int len)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        p[i] = (double)i;

    return 0;
}
%}
```

Output:

```
>>> import x
>>> pd=x.new_doubles(10)
>>> pd
<Swig Object of type 'double *' at 0x0000000002235CC0>
>>> x.myFunc(pd,10)
0
>>> x.doubles_getitem(pd,0)
0.0
>>> x.doubles_getitem(pd,1)
1.0
>>> x.doubles_getitem(pd,9)
9.0
>>> x.delete_doubles(pd)
```

With a little more work, we can get a more Pythonic interface using typemaps.  Below a set of in/argout/argfree typemaps generate type C parameters from a single Python input object.

`%typemap(in)` defines how to convert the Python input to the input parameters.  It checks for an integer object and generates the 2nd parameter (len), then uses `malloc` to generate the 1st parameter.

`%typemap(argout)` defines how to convert the output parameters to a Python object, and appends it to the existing return value represented by `$result`.

`%typemap(free)` frees the allocated parameter from the `in` typemap.

References: [Common typemap methods](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn25), [Multi-argument typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_multi_argument_typemaps)

```
%module x
%include <exception.i>

%typemap(in) (double* p, int len) %{
    if(!PyLong_Check($input))
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_TypeError, "expected integer");
    $2 = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong($input);
    $1 = malloc($2 * sizeof(double));
%}

%typemap(freearg) (double* p, int len) %{
    free($1);
%}

%typemap(argout) (double* p, int len) {
    PyObject* list = PyList_New($2);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < $2; ++i)
        PyList_SET_ITEM(list, i, PyFloat_FromDouble($1[i]));
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, list);
}

%inline %{
int myFunc(double * p, int len)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        p[i] = (double)i;

    return 0;
}
%}
```

Output:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.myFunc(5)
[0, [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
>>> return_value, double_list = x.myFunc(3)
>>> return_value
0
>>> double_list
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```